# Dynamic data validation sheet name for sheet duplication

Tags: validation, google-sheets, copy

So I'm working with a google docs spreadsheet that has a lot of data validation pull-downs, many of which point to cells on that same sheet in its criteria. I need to be able to duplicate the sheet without updating the sheet name in each data validation's criteria, which requires doing it a bunch of times for each sheet (very tedious). *You would think that you could just type the cell range without specifying a sheet and that would do it, but google sheets automatically adds a sheet name to each data validation, even if it's the name of that same sheet.*

Is there a way to designate the sheet name in the criteria in a way that always points to that sheet, similar to a network address 127.0.0.1 which always points to your PC?

Is there a way to "trick" google sheets into updating these sheet names to the new sheet when duplicated? *In the old google sheets, this would happen if I waited 5-10 minutes after duplicating, then proceeded to rename. But the 400,000 cell limit made this prohibitive and the new google sheets doesn't behave this way.*

Is there another way to do this that I haven't thought of? I don't know much about scripting but I'm definitely open to it, if it would solve the problem.

**For instance,** on the original sheet, one pulldown would point to:

```
'James'!B68:F68
```

I'd like to be able to duplicate the sheet named James, rename it to Matt, and have it automatically point to:

```
'Matt'!B68:F68
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a work-around, easier than I thought. When using the triangle icon on the bottom tabs list:

Duplicate will keep all sheet names static for data validation. You won't notice a difference looking at a different reference sheet, until you try to point your data validation at something on its own same sheet. This is what I was using when I had the problem.

Copy to... (even if you select the same sheet you're currently working on) gives you dynamic sheet names on those same sheet data validations. This saves me so much time over updating them manually and makes less room for error.

Thanks for taking a look, I now consider it solved. Feel free to ask questions or whatever. I looked around for a long time online and couldn't find an answer but tinkering did it.